# Pygame Collision Not Working - pygame.sprite.collide_rect()

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm working on a space shooter game and In that game, when an `alien` sprite collides with a `player` sprite, I want the game to end. When wrote the code for the collision, It didn't end the game. Can someone help me?

main.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame
from sprites import *
from config import *

# GAME
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        # INIT PYGAME
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()

        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

        self.player = Player()

    # NEW GAME
    def new(self):
        self.allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.allAliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        for amount in range(ALIEN_AMOUNT):
            self.alien = Alien()
            self.allAliens.add(self.alien)
            self.allSprites.add(self.alien)

        self.allSprites.add(self.player)

        self.run()

    # RUN GAME
    def run(self):
        self.playing = True

        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)

            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
            self.animate()
            self.collision()

    # DRAW
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)

        self.allAliens.draw(self.screen)
        self.allSprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()

    # ANIMATE
    def animate(self):
        pass

    # DETECT COLLISION
    def collision(self):
        # player collition with alien
        hits = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.alien, self.player)

        if hits:
            self.playing = False
            self.running = False

    # CHECK FOR EVENTS
    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False

                self.running = False

    # UPDATE GAME
    def update(self):
        self.allSprites.update()

    # GAME OVER
    def gameOver(self):
        pass

    # START SCREEN
    def startScreen(self):
        pass

    # END SCREEN
    def endScreen(self):
        pass

game = Game()
game.startScreen()

while game.running:
    game.new()
    game.gameOver()

# QUIT
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

sprites.py

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame, random
from config import *

# PLAYER
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/img/player.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT - 50
        self.velX = 0

    def animate(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velX

    def control(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.velX = -5
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.velX = 5
        else:
            self.velX = 0

    def collision(self):
        # collision with walls
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.control()
        self.collision()

# ALIEN
class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/img/rsz_alien.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(10, WIDTH - self.rect.w - 10)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -10)
        self.velY = random.randrange(2, 8)

    def animate(self):
        self.rect.y += self.velY

    def collision(self):
        if self.rect.y > HEIGHT:
            self.reset()

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        self.collision()

    def reset(self):
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -10)
        self.velY = random.randrange(2, 8)
```

There's a `config.py` file but I don't think its needed for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only testing for collision with a single alien (which will be the last one that you created and assigned to `self.alien`). You need to iterate over all the aliens and test for collisions between the player and each of them.

```
def collision(self):
    # player collision with each alien
    for alien in self.allAliens:
        hits = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(alien, self.player)

        if hits:
            self.playing = False
            self.running = False
```